# How data can be stored or retrieved from sessionStorage space of browser using Java Filters?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, filter, sessionstorage

How data can be stored or retrieved from session-storage space of browser using Java Filters ? I want to store some data which is tab specific, hence cookies would not serve the purpose here.

Comment: is your development  framework specific ?
if Spring specific  .
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html

Comment: @Sachin, to answer your question, yes, we are using Spring 3 and we haven't yet migrated to Spring 4 yet. Moreover, the link mentioned by you does not contain any references pointing to session-storage space of browser.